# Phaser overlap doesnt work

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Why my Phaser.js 's overlap work sometimes and doesn't somtimes.
I have enabled arcade for my character and obstacle.
Here are the codes.

```js
function create(){
  ...//other sprite
  obs = game.add.group();
  obs.enableBody = true;
  obstacle = obs.create(800, game.world.height - 68, 'obstacle');
  obstacle.scale.setTo(0.5,0.5);
  game.physics.arcade.enable(obstacle);
  obstacle.events.onOutOfBounds.add(function(obstacle) {
    obstacle.kill(); 
  }, this);
}

function update(){
  ...
  game.physics.arcade.collide(character, obstacle, gameOver, null, this);
}

function generateObs(){//its where i generate new obstacle, and is my biggest suspect as well
  obstacle = obs.create(800, game.world.height - 68, 'obstacle');
  obstacle.scale.setTo(0.5,0.5);
  game.physics.arcade.enable(obstacle);
  obstacle.body.velocity.x = -300;
}
```

Thks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before giving you a possible solution to your problem:

- It is not necessary to apply physics to the element created within
  the group that already has physics.
- If you need to know if two bodies
  overlap but you do not need to emulate a complete collision use 'overlap'.

Try this:

```
var obs;

function create(){
  //Active Physics ARCADE
  game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
  ...//other sprite
  obs = game.add.group();
  obs.enableBody = true;
  obs.physicsBodyType = Phaser.Physics.ARCADE;

  var obstacle = obs.create(800, game.world.height - 68, 'obstacle');
  obstacle.scale.setTo(0.5,0.5);
  obstacle.events.onOutOfBounds.add(function(obstacle) {
    obstacle.kill(); 
  }, this);
}

function update(){
  ...
  //Use the group, since the callback will automatically pass the group element that overlaps with the player. A group is used to handle multiple elements, otherwise use only one variable :)
  game.physics.arcade.overlap(character, obs, gameOver, null, this);
  /*If you want your obstacle to move in the game you must implement this in the Update function
    You can access an element of the group, for this there are multiple methods one of them is to get the element from the element's exists attribute

    var obstacle = obs.getFirstExists(true);
    if (obstacle) { obstacle.body.velocity.x = -300; }
  */ 
}

function gameOver(character, obstacle) {
  //From here you have access to the element that collides with the player (you can evaluate with a condition if it is the obstacle you want)
  //if (obstacle.name == 'x') { console.log(obstacle); }
  console.log('Game Over!');
}

function generateObs(){
  var obstacle = obs.create(800, game.world.height - 68, 'obstacle');
  obstacle.scale.setTo(0.5,0.5);
  obstacle.body.velocity.x = -300;
}
```

Comment: It helps a lot, thks mate!